# What textbook can I use to understand engineering economics?

Tags: reference-request

I'm an Engineering Physics student and this semester I took the course "Engineering Economics" as a requirement to complete the management sciences credits in my program, I need a good textbook to understand engineering economics, thanks.

Comment: Can you post the syllabus? If we see the topics we might be able to recommend something targeted to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the recommended books for our Engineering Economics university course:

**Main Textbook**

N. M. Fraser and E. M. Jewkes, Engineering Economics: Financial Decision Making for Engineers, 5th edition, Pearson, Toronto, Ontario, 2013

**Supplementary Resources**

D. G. Newnan, J. Whittaker, T. G. Eschenbach and J. P. Lavelle, Engineering Economic Analysis, 3rd
edition, Don Mills, Toronto, Ontario, 2014.

J. A. White, K. E. Case and D. B. Pratt, Principles of Engineering Economic Analysis, 5th edition, Hoboken,
NJ, USA, 2010.

I found the main textbook easy to follow. Hope this helps!